# How can I divide a grid map into clusters for path finding algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I am trying to implement HPA algorithm for finding the shortest path between two point. I came across the paper [Near Optimal Path Finding Algorithm](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~mmueller/ps/hpastar.pdf) (by Botea, Müller & Schaeffer) but I am stuck at the clustering part. I have a 2 dimensional array and each index in the array is a node. Could anyone help me clustering my 2 dimensional array into clusters?

Comment: Clustering is a hard problem, with premade maps you can do it manually.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I have a grid map already. It is a 2d array, how can i create clusters from this map.

Comment: What do your maps look like at the moment? Can you show us an example of the types of features you'd like to end up in the same cluster together, and what features should tend to divide clusters?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest implementation is to divide the map into large tiles. For example, this illustration shows a 16 x 16 map clustered into 4x4 tiles:

[image: clustered map example]

While somewhat naive, this approach is very easy to implement, gives consistently sized clusters and due to the hierarchical reduction, may very well give good enough performance.